# "Cannot instantiate the Type Main"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I keep getting this error every time I create a new object with the class name:

"Cannot instantiate the Type Main"

---

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public abstract class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
double x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0;

public Main() {
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    }

public void up() {
    velY = -1.5;
    velX = 0;
    }

public void down() {
    velY = -1.5;
    velX = 0;
    }

public void left() {
    velX = -1.5;
    velY = 0;

    }
public void right() {
    velX = -1.5;
    velY = 0;

    }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up();
        }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left();
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right();
    }

    Main m = new Main();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(m);
    f.setVisible(true);;
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(800,600);

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

And this is the object that keeps getting this "error":

```
Main m = new Main();
```

(I am very very new to making UI's, infact, this is my 3rd, so I have no idea why I cannot instantiate the Type)

Comment: Main is an abstract class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: Ditto on the `abstract` qualifier--just get rid of it. It also looks like the last part of the `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent)` method needs to be moved to a `public static void main(String[])` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't instantiate [abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) in java, Your `Main` class is abstract, make it a concrete Class, since it seems you have all the functionalists and no need to declare it as abstract class.

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener { } //abstract keyword removed
```

Consider using abstract classes if any of these statements apply to your situation:

- You want to share code among several closely related classes.
- You expect that classes that extend your abstract class have many
  common methods or fields, or require access modifiers other than
  public (such as protected and private).
- You want to declare non-static or non-final fields. This enables you
  to define methods that can access and modify the state of the object
  to which they belong.

Answer (score 1):

Your class Main is abstract. One cannot instantiate abstract classes.

Remove the abstract keyword and make sure you implement all necessary methods.

Answer (score 0):

Below line will solve your problem

```
Main m = new Main(){};
```

in place of

```
Main m = new Main();
```

specially in your case.

Comment: By using `Main m = new Main(){};`, you are creating anonymous inner class of `Main`

Comment: Yes I know it. But it will solve the problem as mentioned by OP.